# Creating UIButtons Programmatically - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Relevant code:

```
- (void) createButtons {
    NSMutableArray *buttonTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [buttonTitleArray addObject:@"Website"];
    [buttonTitleArray addObject:@"Blah"];
    [buttonTitleArray addObject:@"Blah"];

    int xPosition = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i <= buttonTitleArray.count-1; i++) {

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 25, 90, 40)];
        button.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitle:[buttonTitleArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:200.0/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1];
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];

        [self.buttonArray addObject:button];
        xPosition += 91;
    }

    for (UIButton *button in self.buttonArray) {

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showWebsite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [self.view addSubview:button];

    }
}

- (void)showWebsite:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Website");
}
```

In init:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.buttonArray = tempArray;
```

For testing purposes I made all the buttons have the same target.

When I click the button, I get unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: Yeah. You are sending a message to an object which it does not recognize. (perhaps if you provided which class and which selector, we could *actually* help...)

Comment: This is button array : @property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *buttonArray;

Comment: And I init it before I call createButtons. I also add objects to buttonArray in for loop...

Comment: Please add the actual error message that mentions the unrecognized selector.

Comment: @RenoJones That doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: Show your error code...what is the name of function you are getting as unrecognized slector ?

Comment: For whatever reason, now I'm getting Thread 1 EXC BAD ACCESS code=1

Comment: your error message should point to showWebsite: ? Can you change it to make it work for "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" ?

Comment: On which line are you getting that

Comment: On main.m - but before I got : [UIGestureDelayedTouch showWebsite:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I don't know why it says UIGestureDelayedTouch....

Comment: Also no different with UIControlEventTouchUpInside - EXC Bad Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your `self` in your posted code gets released and the pointer location gets re-used by the OS as a `UIGestureDelayedTouch`.

Make sure the object that you are creating these buttons in does not get released by the OS before you want to use the `showWebsite` function.

Sometimes people use code like:

```
-(void)function
{
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [someOtherView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

In this case at the end of the function the controller gets released (as there are no further references to it) and anything that could point to it in the future will point to an invalid (deallocated and possibly re-used) object.

UIButton does not retain objects set as targets, so the OS thinks the objects are valid for release if they are not retained by anything else in the program.

Comment: You were exactly right! That fixed the problem. Thank you so much. Really grateful! :)